# Trying to asses an element and change a specific part without changing the rest or without having them in multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, button, selection

So I have created a Periodic table of elements, and what I am trying to do is have someone be able to push a button have some script determine if that element is already there if it is to add a subscript and leave the rest of the chemical formula alone for example I push the Hydrogen button once the Oxygen button once and then realize that I need to push the hydrogen button again I want it to go from HO to H(sub(2))O and keep the O as is without deleting it. how could I do that? I can send you my HTML file if that helps you understand my question more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more helpful with the code, but this is fairly easy. Just use `$(element).html()` to get the information, split the string using `string.split(certain character);` or substrings.

Then add it back to the DOM using `$(element).html(substring1 + "inserted string" + substring2);`

Without jQuery, use the `.innerHTML` attribute of `document.querySelector(element)`, to change the value of the element.

Hope that helps!!